# What is this powershell syntax doing?

Tags: powershell

I've come across the following powershell syntax:

```
([ADSI]"")
```

I realise it is something to do with active directory, but what I want is to understand exactly what the syntax is doing.

Can somebody explain it do me?

I get different results for these two:

```
[ADSI] | get-member
[ADSI]"" | get-member
```

What are those quotes doing?

ADSI on it's own is not recognized, so what are those square brackets doing?

Comment: It would help if you included more context, but it looks like it's creating an emtpy ADSI object. Specifically it is casting an empty string to an ADSI object, but I suspect under the hood that will create an ASDI object with value `$null`

Comment: `[ADSI]` is a type accelerator, a shortcut to `[System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is the same as `New-Object ADSI("")`

> I get different results for these two:
>
> ```
> [ADSI] | get-member
> [ADSI]"" | get-member
> ```

The first one is enumerating the member of the *type* ADSI. The second one is enumerating the members of an *object* (and instance) of type ADSI.

Comment: And, even if you're "not a fan of PoSh", you know enough to give correct answers. Cool.